# Typesafe config: Cannot include multiple files

Tags: typesafe

I am trying to include multiple .config files:
include "../foo1"
include "../foo2"
include "../foo3"
include "../foo4"

Only the last one seems to be effectively included (I have tried different order and always see the result of only the last file being included). 
Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. All the files were included properly, the problem was that all of them contains definition of the same tag (let's say foo: [{},{},{}], so the last include file was clobbering all the previews files. What I needed to do was to merge all these arrays in one.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `include "<file_name>"`, that file is expected to be relatively located with respect to the current config file.

In your case, according to the [docs](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#include-semantics-locating-resources), you should use `file(<file_path>)`.

I hope this is helpful.